# progressbar visiblity gone is not working in fragment

Tags: android, progress-bar

MainActivity I have bottom navigation if user click on the bottom it will show the progressbar ,Once it is moving from activity to fragement want to progressbar visibility gone

but it is not working with below code

MainActivity:

```
progressbar=findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
private void selectFragment(MenuItem item) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        Class fragmentClass;
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.task:
                mTitle.setText("TASK LIST");
                progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                fragmentClass = TaskFragement.class;
                break;

            case R.id.account:
                mTitle.setText("ACCOUNT LIST");
                progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                fragmentClass = AccountFragement.class;
                break;
            case R.id.contact:
                mTitle.setText("CONTACT LIST");
                fragmentClass = ContactFragment.class;
                break;
            case R.id.opportunity:
                mTitle.setText("OPPORTUNITY LIST");
                fragmentClass = SalesStageFragment.class;
                break;

            default:
                fragmentClass = DashboardFragement.class;
        }

        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

    }

public ProgressBar setProgressBarVisibility(int gone) {

        return null;

    }
```

AccountFragement.java:

```
public class AccountFragement extends Fragment {

    public AccountFragement() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     ProgressBar progressBar=((MainActivity)getActivity()).setProgressBarVisibility(GONE);
    
            if(progressBar!=null){
                progressBar.setVisibility(GONE);
            }
 return rootView;
    }
```

Comment: post more code, especially for `AccountFragment`. also `setProgressBarVisibility` method from `MainActivity`

Comment: @snachmsm pls have a look

Comment: You better not to use your Activity from your Fragment, there is a more clean way to handle that with  FragmentLifecycleCallbacks inside your Activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FragmentManager has a nice method called registerFragmentLifecycleCallbacks which helps register a FragmentManager.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks. This allows us to take actions during the fragment's life cycle. You can do something in onFragmentCreated() as you wish.

```
        progressbar=findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    private void selectFragment(MenuItem item) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            Class fragmentClass;
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.task:
                    mTitle.setText("TASK LIST");
                    progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    fragmentClass = TaskFragement.class;
                    break;
    
                case R.id.account:
                    mTitle.setText("ACCOUNT LIST");
                    progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    fragmentClass = AccountFragement.class;
                    break;
                case R.id.contact:
                    mTitle.setText("CONTACT LIST");
                    fragmentClass = ContactFragment.class;
                    break;
                case R.id.opportunity:
                    mTitle.setText("OPPORTUNITY LIST");
                    fragmentClass = SalesStageFragment.class;
                    break;
    
                default:
                    fragmentClass = DashboardFragement.class;
            }
    
            try {
                fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
//add this
            fragmentManager.registerFragmentLifecycleCallbacks(new FragmentManager.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks() {
        
                @Override
                public void onFragmentCreated(FragmentManager fm, Fragment f, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onFragmentCreated(fm, f, savedInstanceState);
                    progressBar.setVisibility(GONE);
                }
            }, true);
    
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
    
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

well, this method return `null` always

```
public ProgressBar setProgressBarVisibility(int gone) {
    return null;
}
```

so this code won't do anything

```
ProgressBar progressBar=((MainActivity)getActivity()).setProgressBarVisibility(GONE);

if(progressBar!=null){
    progressBar.setVisibility(GONE);
}
```

remove this code and place new method in `Activity` like this:

```
public void setProgressBarVisibility(boolean visible) {
    if(progressbar==null) return; // not inited yet
    progressbar.setVisibility(visible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
}
```

hide your `progressbar` from `AccountFragement` like below

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = ...

    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).setProgressBarVisibility(false);
    return rootView;
}
```